# Set Docker machine on static IP using VMWare workstation

Tags: docker, docker-machine, vmware-workstation

I use Docker on Windows with a VMWare Workstation VM (NOT Docker for Windows - that is different and uses Hyper V).  Docker on VMWare Workstation works great, but don't see any Docker documentation on how to set up a static IP on the Docker machine.  The vm uses DHCP every time.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this line in `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh`, and `bootsync.sh` is the startup file executed before the Docker daemon starts ([according to the manpage on Github](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition))

```
# ifconfig eth1 192.168.126.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.126.255 up
```

So perhaps the folks managin boot2docker suggest this is the place to set the ip.  However, you need to change `eth1` to `eth0` to make it work.

This breaks docker in other places.  `docker-machine ssh default` still has the old ip address.  `docker-machine ip` still lists the wrong IP address.  But you can see to the static IP you set.  So I consider this a partial solution.